# Javascript ignoring variable in switch statement

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to make a case statement but my variable for my first switch statement just goes to my default statement when i really have a string in my variable for the type of edge such as: "round", "square", "butt". I tested it with alert(tipoextremo) and it does contain the value "round", "square", or "butt".

For the second switch statement, i am trying to get my button names into the switch statement when i click a button in html and do that function inside the case, but when using alert("hi") it does not even go into the default statement meaning that it is being completely ignored in my javascript.

```
        <section id="cajalienzo">
            <p>
                Botones
                <button name="btnborrar" type="button" value="borrar" onclick="fun_borrar()">
                    Borrar
                </button>
                <button name="btnlineas" type="button" value="variaslineas" onclick="fun_variaslineas()">
                    Varias Lineas
                </button>
                <button name="btnarco" type="button" value="arco" onclick="parametros()">
                    Arco
                </button>
                <button name="btncuad" type="button" value="cuad" onclick="parametros()">
                    Cuadratica
                </button>
                <button name="btnbezier" type="button" value="bezier" onclick="parametros()">
                    Berzier
                </button>
                <button name="btnzigzag" type="button" value="zigzag" onclick="parametros()">
                    Zig Zag
                </button>
                <button name="btnespiral" type="button" value="espiral" onclick="parametros()">
                    Espiral
                </button>
            </p>
        </section>

        <section id="parametros">
            <form action="" method="post" name="parametro">
                Color: <input type="text" name="btncolor" id="color" value="red"><br/>
                Ancho: <input type="text" name="btnancho" id="ancho" value="10"><br/>
                Tipo Extremo: <br/>
                Round   <input type="radio" name="btntipoextremo" value="round" id="tipoextremo" checked="checked"><br/>
                Square  <input type="radio" name="btntipoextremo" value="square" id="tipoextremo"><br/>
                Butt    <input type="radio" name="btntipoextremo" value="butt" id="tipoextremo"><br/>
                <button name="btnOK" type="button" value="OK" onclick="parametros()">OK</button>
            </form>
       </section>
```

This is my javascript part.

```
function parametros() {
 //var nombre = document.parametro.btncolor.value;
 //alert(nombre);

  contexto.beginPath();
  color = document.getElementById("color").value;
  ancho = document.getElementById("ancho").value;

alert(color);
alert(ancho);

var boton_te = document.forms[0];
var i;
for (i = 0; i < boton_te.length; i++) {
    if (boton_te[i].checked) {
        tipoextremo = tipoextremo + boton_te[i].value + " ";
    }
}
document.getElementById("tipoextremo").value = tipoextremo;
tipoextremo = tipoextremo;
alert(tipoextremo);

switch(tipoextremo) {
    case 'round':
        alert("hi");
    break;
    case 'square':
        alert("hi");
    break;
    case 'butt':
        alert("hi");
    break;
    default:
        alert("hi");
    break;
}

$("input[type='button']").click(function()
{
    switch(this.name){
    case 'btnarco':
        fun_arco(color, ancho, tipoextremo);
        break;
    case 'btncuad':
        fun_cuad(color, ancho, tipoextremo);
        break;
    case 'btnbezier':
        fun_bezier(color, ancho, tipoextremo);
        break;
    case 'btnzigzag':
        fun_zigzag(color, ancho, tipoextremo);
        break;
    case 'btnespiral':
        fun_espiral(color, ancho, tipoextremo);
        break;
    default:
        alert("hi");
    break;
    }
 });
}
```

Comment: What error do you get in the browser console?

Comment: This would be better suited to StackOverflow

Comment: @brianlmerritt im using notepad++ but is there a way to see errors? i actually see part of my javascript working

Comment: @Burgi do i need to create a new account?

Comment: You can use your SuperUser account. With reference to being able to see the JS errors, open the developer console in your browser (usually F12)

Comment: @brianlmerritt i have this error Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined in this line $("input[type='button']").click(function()

Comment: Are you loading jQuery?

Comment: @brianlmerritt no i dont have any jquery other than that part i have the $ sign... is there another way of doing that if im doing it wrong?? or do i have to add something to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

`$` only works if you have jQuery loaded. You can get it from a CDN, by adding this to your html `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` before your Javascript above.